# How should you perform a manipulation check for multiple items that should belong to one of two groups?

Tags: anova, experiment-design

Suppose I have 8 creatures that participants rate on my YuckFactor scale. I chose 4 cute animals to be part of a LowYuck group and 4 ugly bugs to be part of the HighYuck group. How can I test that each living creature is significantly different than the opposite group?

It seems like I may have to run 8 anovas comparing each creature to the 4 creatures in the contrasting group. Any other suggestions are welcome.

EDIT: To answer questions from the comments:
Each participant rate all creatures. The ratings are numerical scores on a scale from 1 to 7. The creates are presented in random order.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the ratings are conducted?  For instance, does each participant rate all creatures or just some? Are the ratings numerical scores or are they simple rankings?  What is the experimental design?  (For instance, are creatures presented to participants in random orders or a fixed order?)

Comment: @whuber I added clarification in the body of the question.  Each participant rate all creatures. The ratings are numerical scores on a scale from 1 to 7. The creates are presented in random order.